# disallowed field validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, validation

I'm new with spring framework. I'm currently building some **news** manager form.

Here a sample of my news entity :

```
class News
{
    @NotNull
    long id;
    @NotNull
    long idAuthor;
    @Size(max=255)
    String content;
}
```

As you can see, I use JSR303 annotation validation with Spring. I want to validate my "news edit form".

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/edit" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editAction(@Valid @ModelAttribute News news, BindingResult result)
    {   
        System.err.println(result.hasErrors());
          ...
            return "editView";
    }
```

Define allowed field :

```
//initBinder function :
     binder.setAllowedFields("content");
```

Well, i'm trying to validate only "content" field (allowed field set on my binder)... But Spring always validate all the field defined on my entity (so "id" & "idAuthor" return error)

**How can i only validate allowed field (set on initBinder function) ?**

Comment: Did I have to create a special entity with "content" field only ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no good ways to do it.

JSR-303 offers two approaches for selective validation:

- You may validate specific properties by calling `validator.validateProperty(news, "content")`
- You may define validation groups:

  ```
  @Size(max=255, groups = {Default.class, WebValidation.class})      
  String content;
  ```

  And validate the specified group: `validator.validate(news, WebValidation.class);`

None of these approaches are directly supported by Spring MVC. You can autowire a JSR-303 `Validator` and call these methods manually, but they return `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>`, and the code for putting these `ConstraintViolation`s into `BindingResult` is buried deep inside the Spring internals and can't be easily reused (see [`SpringValidatorAdapter`](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/SpringValidatorAdapter.java)).

There is a feature request for supporting validation groups in `@Valid`-style approach ([SPR-6373](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6373)) with fix version 3.1.

So, aside from creating a special DTO class, you doesn't have many options: you can use manual validation (without JSR-303), or you can copy-paste the code from `SpringValidatorAdapter` into your own utility method and manually call the methods of JSR-303 `Validator`.